# list-style-image not working properly in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple list and want to use list-style-image to set the images for the list-items. I have set text-align: center on the list items because i want the list items to be on the center of the screen along with the list-images.

This works exactly how I want it to work in firefox. But in chrome the list-style-images are aligned to the far-left of the screen. Any idea why this is caused and how can I fix this bug on chrome?

I have made a JSFiddle here and you can see how i want it to appear on firefox and the issue on chrome: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jhchmo5w/1/

```
<div class="discover-content">
   <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item Item Item 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List Item b 5</li>
    <li>List Item cd 6</li>
   </ul>
</div>

.discover-content ul li {text-align: center;}
.discover-content ul li {
            margin-top: 9px; 
            padding-left: 12px;
            list-style: none;
            list-style-position: outside;
            list-style-image: url(http://www.expertfrontend.com/icons/tick-red.png);
             text-align: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list-style-position: inside;` will work well both for Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `list-style-position:outside` and add `list-style-position:inside` to get the `images and text` on `centre`.

Check this out...

```css
.discover-content ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
.discover-content ul li {
  margin-top: 9px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: url(http://www.expertfrontend.com/icons/tick-red.png);
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="discover-content">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item Item Item 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List Item b 5</li>
    <li>List Item cd 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```